# FloatingActionButton backgroundTint animation

Tags: android

I'd like to animate the backgroundTint value (and ideally the alpha value too) of a FloatingActionButton, so that the FAB background color continuously switches between two colors.

My noob approach would be to use a timer that calls a function that updates this property when it fires. I'm sure there's a better way of doing this?

Comment: Do you mean you want to periodically change (set) the FAB's background colour, or actually animate it continuously (basically crossfading one colour value to the next)? If it's the latter, I would definitely use a ObjectAnimator or ValueAnimator. The basic idea with some implementation details are outlined is [this G+ post from Cyril Mottier](https://plus.google.com/+CyrilMottier/posts/X4yoNHHszwq).

Comment: I think ideal way to deal with it would be animation.

Comment: @MH. I ideally want to crossfade. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I got this to work using ObjectAnimator as suggested by @MH. above, but I had to override the onAnimationUpdate() callback:

```
final ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(Color.rgb(0, 121, 107), Color.rgb(226, 143, 34));
animator.setDuration(2000L);
animator.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
animator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator(2));
animator.addUpdateListener(new ObjectAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        int animatedValue = (int) animation.getAnimatedValue();
        fab.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(animatedValue));
    }
});
animator.start();
```

Comment: Suppose I have a percentage of how much to go, instead of the `animation.getAnimatedValue` , how can I use it instead?

Comment: Use ValueAnimator.ofObject, with an ArgbEvaluator instead: `ValueAnimator.ofObject(ArgbEvaluatorCompat.getInstance(),  prevColor, newColor).start();`