# How to directly (without animation) set FAB icon rotation&color and FAB background, at runtime?

Tags: android, floating-action-button, objectanimator

### Background

I'm making a POC of swiping a FAB up and down, similar to how it works on the Phone app, when you get a phone call:

[image] [image]

### The problem

While I've handled the touch events (allowing to move the fab up and down), and animate back when you stop touching, I also need to change the background color of the FAB and rotation&color of the icon of the FAB.

### What I've found

I've found only solutions for animating of the FAB background color and its icon rotation:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/31652716/878126
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/35517240/878126

I didn't find how to change the color of the icon itself, though.

But in my case, it can't be done using just animation, because the FAB has its Y coordinate change based on touch, so the values need to adapt right away, without animation.

Here's my current code:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:clipChildren="false" android:clipToPadding="false"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fabTouchingAreaView" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal" android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:clipChildren="false" android:clipToPadding="false" tools:background="#33ff0000">

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom" android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp" android:tint="#0f0" app:backgroundTint="#fff"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/stat_sys_phone_call"/>
    </FrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val yToResetTo = (fab.layoutParams as ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams).topMargin.toFloat()
        val argbEvaluator = ArgbEvaluator()
        fabTouchingAreaView.setOnTouchListener(object : View.OnTouchListener {
            val WHITE_COLOR = 0xffffffff.toInt()
            val RED_COLOR = 0xffff0000.toInt()
            val GREEN_COLOR = 0xff00ff00.toInt()
            var startTouchY = Float.MIN_VALUE
            var startViewY = Float.MIN_VALUE
            var maxToGoTo = Float.MIN_VALUE
            var animator: ObjectAnimator? = null

            fun updateView() {
                val newY = fab.y
                val percentDown = if (newY <= yToResetTo) 0.0f else ((newY - yToResetTo) / (maxToGoTo - yToResetTo))
                val percentUp = if (newY >= yToResetTo) 0.0f else (1.0f - (newY / yToResetTo))
                // need code here to update content
            }

            override fun onTouch(view: View, motionEvent: MotionEvent): Boolean {
                when (motionEvent.action) {
                    MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                        if (animator != null) {
                            animator!!.cancel()
                            animator = null
                        }
                        startTouchY = motionEvent.rawY
                        startViewY = fab.y
                        maxToGoTo = fabTouchingAreaView.height.toFloat() - fab.height
                    }
                    MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                        if (animator == null) {
                            animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(fab, View.Y, yToResetTo)
                            //TODO use normal animate() when minSdk is at least 19
                            animator!!.addUpdateListener { animation -> updateView() }
                            animator!!.start()
                        }
                    }
                    MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                        val newY = Math.min(Math.max(startViewY + (motionEvent.rawY - startTouchY), 0.0f), maxToGoTo)
                        fab.y = newY
                        updateView()
                    }
                }
                return true
            }
        })
    }
}
```

And here's a demonstration of how it works:

[image]

One possible workaround would be to have multiple views instead of a single FAB, which I choose how to animate between them, but this is just a workaround...

### The questions

1. How can I change the background color of the FAB, at runtime, similar to the Phone app, by using just the percentage of how far I got ?
2. How can I change the rotation&color of the icon of the FAB, at runtime, similar to the Phone app, by using just the percentage of how far I got ?

---

EDIT: seeing the accepted answer, the next code will do what I've written, in the `updateView` function:

```
                val fabBackgroundColor = when {
                    percentDown > 0f -> argbEvaluator.evaluate(percentDown, WHITE_COLOR, RED_COLOR) as Int
                    percentUp > 0f -> argbEvaluator.evaluate(percentUp, WHITE_COLOR, GREEN_COLOR) as Int
                    else -> WHITE_COLOR
                }
                val fabIconColor = when {
                    percentDown > 0f -> argbEvaluator.evaluate(percentDown, GREEN_COLOR, WHITE_COLOR) as Int
                    percentUp > 0f -> argbEvaluator.evaluate(percentUp, GREEN_COLOR, WHITE_COLOR) as Int
                    else -> GREEN_COLOR
                }
                fab.setColorFilter(fabIconColor)
                fab.backgroundTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(fabBackgroundColor)
                fab.rotation = percentDown * 135
                Log.d("appLog", "y:" + fab.y + " percentDown:$percentDown percentUp:$percentUp " +
                        "fabBackgroundColor:${Integer.toHexString(fabBackgroundColor)} fabIconColor:${Integer.toHexString(fabIconColor)}")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I change the background color of the FAB, at runtime, similar
>   to the Phone app, by using just the percentage of how far I got ?

you can use `ArgbEvaluator` to calculate the color for the current position, and set the return value of `evaluate` as new Background.

> How can I change the rotation of the icon of the FAB, at runtime,
>   similar to the Phone app, by using just the percentage of how far I
>   got ?

as above, use an `Interpolator` to calculate the rotation and the use `View.setRotation` to rotate it

Comment: About colors, I think using `backgroundTintList` for the FAB background works. But what should I use for the icon within? Seems `setColorFilter` works for it, but is it correct? About `View.setRotation`, some people claimed it doesn't work on old Android versions, as it rotates the shadow, but I've tested it and it seems to work fine even on Android 4.2. Is it indeed safe?

Comment: for the icon you could try tinting (`DrawableCompat.setTint(`) the drawable (`Fa`b is an `ImageView` and has the `getDrawable()` method). I dunno if it works but I would give it a try

Comment: But maybe setColorFilter is ok too? I've tested it, and it seems to work fine on various Android versions, from 4.2 to P .